# FME Feature Type with Python

Tags: python, esri-geodatabase, fme-form

Here, the Python for create a list of feature types but....

```
import sys
from pyfme import *
try:
    log=FMELogfile("shapeToTAB.log")

    log.log("Opening reader",FME_INFORM)
    reader=FMEReader("GEODATABASE_FILE")
    reader.open("C:\depot\export\TE-PMB.gdb")

    GeomList = []

    schemaFeature=FMEFeature()
    log.log("Copying schema features")
    while reader.readSchema(schemaFeature):
        GeomList.append(schemaFeature.getFeatureType())
        log.logFeature(schemaFeature)

    reader.close()
    print GeomList

except FMEException, err:
    print "FMEException: %s" % err
    sys.exit(1)
```

I would like **return** a list of feature type of my geodatabase.
Is it possible ?

Comment: I formatted the code and tried to keep the original indentation while doing so, but it makes no sense to me: you had better double-check it to make sure it is correctly rendered.

Comment: Hi, I edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **PythonTableViewer** to see your Features Types and Tables

http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/PythonTableViewer

Helpful with a little modification

http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/Extracting_Geodatabase_coded_domain_definition_tables